# Regex to take only domain specific email

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have written one regex to take only email domain as yahoo.com.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@yahoo\.com$"
```

but when i enter amit.sahay@yahoo.com, it says invalid email id.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `.` is not added in character class `"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@yahoo\.com$"`

Comment: Or you could just use [`string.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i think you must also check for invalid characters in email address like parenthesis or semicolons etc... @DavidG

Answer (score 1):

You didn't added `.(dot)` within your character class over here so your updated regex would be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@yahoo\.com$
         //^^ added (.dot) over here
```